# How looks good structure of construct for creating multidimensial array

Tags: php, xml, foreach, constructor

I am trying to create constructor which creates an multidimensional array. My result should be like this:-

[Checkout my array $result_array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMUkm.png)

For now I have error: Illegal offset type. Note that I have als use __toString() becose I work on xml data.

```
class Property {

    public $xmlClass;
    public $elemClass = '';
    public $first_array = array();
    public $result_array = array();
    public $data = '';
    public $data2 = '';

    public function __construct($xml, $elem) {
        $this->xmlClass = $xml;
        $this->elemClass = $elem;

        foreach ($xml->xpath('//*[@baza]') as $val) {
            $this->first_array[] = $val;
            foreach ($val->ksiazka as $value) {
                $data = $value->$elem->__toString();
                $this->result_array[$this->first_array][] = $data;
            }
        }
    }

    public function getResult() {
        return $this->result_array;
    }

}

$result_autor = new Property($xml, 'autor');
$autor = $result_autor->getResult();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***You need to change your two `foreach()` like below:-***

```
foreach($xml->xpath('//*[@baza]') as $val) {
    //$this->first_array[] = $val; not needed
    foreach($val->ksiazka as $key=> $value){ //check $key here
      $data = $value->$elem->__toString();
      $this->result_array[$key][] = $data; // add $key hear
    }
}
```

***If the above not worked then check this too:-***

```
foreach($xml->xpath('//*[@baza]') as $key=> $val) { //check $key here
    //$this->first_array[] = $val; not needed
    foreach($val->ksiazka as $value){ 
      $data = $value->$elem->__toString();
      $this->result_array[$key][] = $data; // add $key hear
    }
}
```

Comment: That`s it! Thank you very much, for both examples. I am still learning how it works.

Comment: @Michał  glad to help you :):)